# Let R be a ring and f: M→N is an R-homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let R be a ring and f: M→N is a R homomorphism.

1. If f is monomorphism Annhilator(N)⊆ Annihilator(M).
2. If f is an isomorphism Annhilator(M)=Annihilator(N).

I need to prove these propositions, I started to prove them by the definition of monomorphism and isomorphism but couldn't connect with the annhilator. Also I used the if f is monomorphism Kerf=0 theorem too.

Comment: Let R be a ring, and let M be a left R-module. Choose a non-empty subset S of M. The annihilator of S, denoted Ann(S), is the set of all elements r in R such that, for all s in S, rs = 0. In set notation Ann(S)= {r∈R| ∀ s ∈ S : rs=0}

Answer (score 4):

Let $r \in \operatorname{Ann}(N)$. We need to show that $r \in \operatorname{Ann}(M)$, that is, that $r \cdot m = 0$ for all $m \in M$. Since $f$ is a monomorphism, it is enough to show that $f(r \cdot m )=0$. Can you go from here?

The second proposition is implied by the first (hint: consider the inverse of $f$).

Comment: I am going to try right now and how we will solve is f is an epimorphism?Because I thought I prove it correctly but our ways to go are kinda different.

Comment: You could show that if $f$ is an epimorphism then $Ann(M) \subseteq Ann(N)$. This will be very similar to the monomorphism proof - try it out

Comment: finally I understand thank you so much,

Answer (score 3):

Hint on 1).

If $r$ annihilates $N$ then:

$f(rm)=rf(m)=0=f(0)$ for every $m\in M$.

Comment: yes I get this part but still couldn't figured out how I'll make the ending and show what the question want me prove.

Comment: In this context monomorphisms are injective. Then what can you conclude from $f(rm)=f(0)$ if $f$ is a monomorphism?...

Comment: oh I understand thank you so much